# Linking from List Item to Multiple Documents in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, list-item, attachments

I've created a SharePoint List containing employee names.  I would like to be able to link each entry to an associated set of completed training records for each employee.  What is the best way to achieve this?  Can each item (employee name) be linked to a separate set of documents (presumable within a separate library?), or is it better to just apply the documents as attachments to each item?

The number of training records can vary widely, from just a couple to several dozen

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 3):

The approach with separate document library is definitely better than the one with attachments.

You should create a document library, enable content types (Document library settings -> advanced settings -> set "Allow management of content types?" to Yes) and add the "Document Set" content type to the document library (Document set is actually the special type of Folder and can contain multiple documents).

Then, you should add a lookup column to your list that contains employee details.

This way you will be able to create a new document set for each employee (which contains all the necessary documents), and then to link it to the employee using the lookup column. Also, there is a possibility to reuse one document set for multiple employees if necessary.

Comment: Damjan -  This approach worked perfectly.  Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: This is the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your specific requirements, it sounds you could simply create a lookup column (allow multiple selections) on your employee list. The lookup column source would be your training documents library.

Hope this helps!

Update: Damjan Tomic's approach is definitely better if the documents are specific to a single employee, which they probably are being training records and all. Good call!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem - my approach was to put on a filtered list of a document library on the editform of the list - then add an 'add document' - link which invokes javascript to add a document to the associated document library.  It passes the list item id as part of the URL.  (you can't just invoke the document library upload.aspx - this won't get you the desired result).  Then - in the editform of the document library - you invoke some javascript which grabs the index id of the list item (it gets from the URL) - and then us spjs-utility scripts (specifically setFieldValue() ) to default the index value column on the document to the list item id.